# Store mysqli queries in php "matrixes"

Tags: php, matrix, mysqli

Let's assume I have a table similar to this:

```
Id Name Value1 Value2 Value3
1  Bla  1      5      1
2  Blu  4      0      2
```

How to I put this into a matrix format (or similar) in PHP  so I can work with it?

I wanted to do some calculations and sorting with the part that contains:

```
1  5  1
4  0  2
```

So I could then order and permantely change the main matrix. For example:

Assign a weight of 50% (or other) to each column and then move the columns associated with the lower values to the left.

Example:

```
1*0.5 + 4*0.5 = 2.5
5*0.5 + 0*0.5 = 2.5
1*0.5 + 2*0.5 = 1.5
```

Final output:

```
Id Name Value3 Value2 Value1
1  Bla  1      5      1
2  Blu  2      0      4
```

In C this was very easy to do but in PHP seems to me it's very complicated to do this because there isn't an object like M[i,j].

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the column in each iteration of your query, you can't access it directly like you can with a row result:

```
$values = array();
$multiplier = 0.5;

foreach($result as $row) {
    $values[1] += $row['value1'] * $multiplier;
    $values[2] += $row['value2'] * $multiplier;
    $values[3] += $row['value3'] * $multiplier;
}

print_r($values);
```

Depending on the names of your columns though, you could loop through them in PHP to define variables or array keys instead of doing it by hand (especially if you have lots of them). Depends on your column names. If you have lots that aren't related by numbers etc, you could loop through the column names and exclude certain ones e.g. id, name etc from your processing. In that case, you'd leave the first line above, insert a variable in place of `1` and `value1`, and **check to make sure the array key exists** before using the `+=` operator as it will often throw an error if it's not already defined:

```
if(!array_key_exists($yourfield, $values))
    $values[$yourfield] = 0;
// continue...
```

Comment: So... there is no way to store the data of a querry in a matrix? That would make working with database so easy :z
I'm really tired but tomorrow I take a look at this with a fresh head. In this particular case I would need to go from column 3 to 63 and rows really depend on the querry (max rows would be around 20 but in table there are around 400 rows).

Comment: So basically you are saying that if I have 20 rows in the querry and I want to operate with the columns I need to do a querry per row resulting in 20 queries for each column? This would lead to around 1200 queries each time... Isn't this a lot?

Comment: No, you'll loop through your **columns**, you're always going to have to run through all your rows anyway, unless you want to do these calculations in your SQL query (which I think you'll need to know your column names already to do - not dynamically). When you say matrix... an array will give you the desired structured data you're after, is that what you mean?